# typeerror: list indices must be integers or slices not str: trying to loop through table elements in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a piece of code where I'm trying to loop through a table in selenium and store the text in a list to check if it matches the user input:

```
 def choose_class(self):
    crsNums = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='table1']/tbody/tr/td")
    crsList = []
    for i in crsNums:
        classes = i.text
        crsList.append(classes)
        print(crsList)

        for j in crsList:
            if int(crsList[j]) == crn:
                chsnclass = crsList[j]
                webdriver.ActionChains(driver).double_click(chsnclass).key_down(Keys.META).send_keys('c').perform()
```

I get an an error saying that the index must be an int, when the I get the user input I do a conversion to make sure it's an int: `crn = int(input("Enter the CRN (course registration #): "))` but it still doesn't work?

Comment: Always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because j, which is classes ,which is i.text is not integer probably. if you are sure it is a string that contains numbers, then `crsList[int(j)]` could solve the problem

Comment: change for loop to :  for j in range(len(crsList)):

Comment: You could have appended the above comment within the main answer for betterment.

Comment: Actually i've noticed you can undo my suggestions, and replace crsList[j] with j in two places. But be carefull  you must also now chsnclass is whether integer or string,if you dont know just try both. Just be aware of types man :).

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Yeah you are right, i've noticed too